# Which HTML tag is mandatory when using the <thead> HTML tag?

Tags: html, css

I am confused about this ques that is it, mandatory to use any of the below tags when we use `<thead>` tag?

`<tbody>`
`<tfoot>`

Both of the above or none of the above?

Comment: No, if you do not add a `tbody`, the browser will add it for you. `tfoot` is not a mandatory element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither are required! But it's a cleaner to add `tbody` when you have a `thead`.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```